# Ajax: Not able to send with success second request as it requires sessionid

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, leaflet

My application is based on LeafletJS API so it's limited to javascript and Webview(because I am compiling application for mobile phones).
So Index.html file will always be located locally on device and it will work as an application.
I would like to add option for users to be able to login to my application and when they are logged in they can add markers on map and some additional data.
So I wrote  php files to add login/register function and queries to mysql server as a backend.
This files must be on the server, so to access them I need to send request to login or run query in one of this files.

I created Ajax request but the issue is that sessionID is not being cached.
So I am able to create request to login but when I am trying to send another request to query I am not able to do that because user is not logged(no sessionID).
I would like to keep settings like that for security reason, if there is any better way to do login/register and queries suggestions are more than welcome.
I tried to use **xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');** to get sessionid.
But then I am receiving:
**The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.**

I cannot change wildcard '*' to any ip address as mobile users will send requests from different ip address.
Can someone please suggest me some changes to get everything work together?
Thank you

Comment: so, you need to change the server code to send an access control allow origin header with the received `origin` request header - I take it you do have some control over the server side code

Comment: you can fudge it by reading the IP address the request is coming from and dynamically setting the allow-origin header to that IP each time.

Comment: @ADyson - the IP address of the request is not the `origin` ... the `origin` header is the `origin`, which is the **website** of the requests origin (nothing to do with the client)

Comment: `as mobile users` - are irrelevant, the origin is the (cross origin) website the request is initiated by - read the [mdn CORS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) - it explains much

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry yes you're technically correct, although the OP did mention this would be a .html file locally on the mobile device itself.

Comment: you can't fudge CORS when accessing a file on the local file system